# How can I preserve spaces in user input for bat scripts?

Tags: batch-file, spaces, preserve

I have a bat script to dump a list of user names and their display name from Active Directory. It works great until a group we need to dump names from a group that has a space.

```
@echo off
Set /p GROUP="Group Name: "

echo This window will close when finished!
echo Larger groups may take awhile!

 dsquery group -name %Group% | DSGET group -members | dsget user -samid -display > %GROUP%.txt
```

Is there a way to preserve spaces with user input? This is a remote server at work, so I don't have privileges to install applications or anything, just create basic scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup, just a matter of enclosing the var string in "", try this:

dsquery group -name "%Group%" | DSGET group -members | dsget user -samid -display > %GROUP%.txt

Comment: Wow.. Of all the things to try, it was something simple and over looked.. lol. Thanks, I just applied it and the script ran perfectly!